# How do I count scores over 90 in sql

Tags: sql, oracle, counting

I want to count scores over 90, but this ends up counting the total rows

```
select g.score as score
      ,count(case when g.score>=90 then 1 else 0 end) over () as passed
from grades g
```

If my data is

```
100
45
90 
100
```

it should show 3, but instead it shows 4

Answer (score 2):

You either remove the `ELSE` part so default is NULL and `COUNT` doesnt count NULL

```
select g.score as score
      ,count(case when g.score>=90 then 1 end) over () as passed
from grades g
```

or change `COUNT` for `SUM`

```
select g.score as score
      ,SUM(case when g.score>=90 then 1 else 0 end) over () as passed
from grades g
```

Answer (score 2):

Simply edit `COUNT` in `SUM`. `COUNT` counts not null values, so it even counts 0; `SUM` will only 'count' non zero values